# How to tell if I'm on the last iteration of a for X in Y loop in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a loop using the for (NSObject *obj in someArray) { } syntax. Is there an easy way to tell if I'm on the last iteration of the loop (ie. without having to use [someArray count])

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe this will work?

```
if ( obj == [ someArray lastObject ] ) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You could use `NSArray#lastObject` to determine if `obj` is equal to `[NSArray lastObject]`.

```
for (NSObject *obj in someArray) {
    if ([someArray lastObject] == obj) {
        NSLog(@"Last iteration");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather than call into the array at every iteration, it **might** be better to cache the last object in the array:

```
NSObject *lastObject = [someArray lastObject];
for (NSObject *obj in someArray) {

    // Loop code

    if (obj == lastObject) {
        // do what you want for the last array item
    }
}
```

Comment: You're still calling the method in the loop. I think you meant to swap the first two lines. Another tiny typo: uppercase 'F' in "For"